# почему не происходит передача данных в реальном времени через socket.io (node.js, express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

в отдельном файле делается запрос в базу данных Monogodb, полученные данные должны передаться пользователю с помощью socket.io, но этого не происходит. Но если серверную часть прописать в одном файле то все работает нормально. В чем ошибка?

```js
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const layout = require("./routes/gaming-industry-layout")
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const port = process.env.port || 3000

const urlecodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'))
app.use(gameind)

app.set("view engine", "ejs")

app.use(layout)

http.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Port- ${port}`)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...

</head>
<body>   
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      socket.on('one', function(msg) {
        console.log(msg)
      });
      </script>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/:id', (req, res)=>{

    const url = 'URL базы данных'
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("newdb")
        dbo.collection("students").find({}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(3).toArray((err, results)=>{ 
            console.log("DataBase ok")
            io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    
                console.log("socket ok")
                socket.emit('one', results);
            
            });
         })

        db.close()
    })
})

module.exports = app
```

Comment: экспорт роута пишется вот так https://expressjs.com/ru/guide/routing.html#express-router

Comment: вот тут хороший пример с сокетами stackoverflow.com/a/31732867